# Error COMException. Utilizar DLL - Type Mismatch

Tags: c#

Amigos Buenas Tardes! Por favor su ayuda con lo siguiente.

Me han entregado una DLL la cual no tengo idea de en que lenguaje se programó y tampoco estoy seguro de que sea un objeto para utilizar en ambientes .NET. Esta dll se encuentra encriptada, pero la idea es poder utilizar una función la cual se encuentra en ella. Esta función se define de al siguiente forma:

Validate(String PW, ref String EncrPW, ref String Status);

Al ser invocada de la siguiente forma:

```
        try
        {
            ODBMSSecEncr D = new ODBMSSecEncr();
            D.Validate("mflores",ref EncrPW, ref Status);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Arroja el siguiente error:

**ErrorCode:**-2146828275
**Message:** Type mismatch
**StackTrace:**   en ODBMSSec._ODBMSSecEncr.Validate(String PW, String& EncrPW, String& Status)
   en ControlInsumos.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\JADM\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ControlInsumos\ControlInsumos\Global.asax.cs:línea 32

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor vuestra ayuda con esto! 
Gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente sea una **DLL** que tengas que registrar con ayuda del **Regsvr32**

Intenta hacer esto:

1. Si tu PC es de 32 bits

Copia el DLL a la carpeta: **C:\Windows\SysWoW64**

Luego ejecuta esto en el cmd (con privilegios de admin) **%windir%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe %windir%\SysWoW64\nombre_de_tu_dll.dll**

2. Si tu PC es de 64 bits

Copia el DLL a la carpeta: **C:\Windows\System32**

Luego ejecuta esto en el cmd (con privilegios de admin) **%windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe %windir%\System32\nombre_de_tu_dll.dll**

Suerte.

Comment: Hola Wanderson, Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero el error sigue pasando. :(